# Is this a correct way of using AND,OR in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a private message system just like in a simple forum website. But im not sure if the SELECT query is in correct way. 
Im trying to show every message on the chat box therefore for example userA sent a message to userB and userB might sent another message to userA. But im keep getting "problem" string (which is in else statement, wouldnt query...).

````
            $alici = $_GET['user'];
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $mesajlar = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sender_name=:s AND receiver_name=:r OR sender_name=:s2, AND receiver_name=:r2");
            $mesajlar->execute([':s'=>$username, ':r'=>$alici, ':s2'=>$alici, ':r2'=>$username]);

             
            if ($mesajlar->rowCount() > 0) {
                foreach ($mesajlar as $mesajlar_each) {
                    $sender_name = $mesajlar_each['sender_name'];
                    $receiver_name = $mesajlar_each['receiver_name'];
                    $messsage = $mesajlar_each['message_text'];

                    if($sender_name == $username){
                        ?>
                            <div class="grey-message">
                                <a href="#"> Me </a>
                                <p> <?php echo $message; ?> </p>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else{
                        ?>
                            <div class="white-message">
                                <a href="#"> <?php echo $sender_name; ?> </a>
                                <p><?php echo $message; ?> </p>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    }

                }
                 
            }
            else{
                //problem
                echo "problem";
            }

            ?> 
    
    ```
````

Comment: No. Never use `SELECT *`, and, as I think you've guessed, your syntax is wrong

Comment: there are no such operators in PDO. It's SQL operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might write that this way:

```
$query = "
    SELECT c.olumns
         , y.ou
         , a.ctually
         , n.eed
      FROM messages m
     WHERE (:s,:r) IN ((m.sender_name,m.receiver_name)
                      ,(m.receiver_name,m.sender_name))";

$mesajlar = $pdo->prepare($query);
$mesajlar->execute(['s' => $username,'r' => $alici]);
$result = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: I used paranthesis just like you wrote, still didnt work :( what about the
$mesajlar-execute part ?

Comment: oh it worked!!! thank you so much!!! 
I can clearly see where is my problem now.
I would like to ask more one question, Why we did put "messages m" ? not only "messages" ? what is the purpose or meaning there

Comment: I habitually alias my tables (m), and qualify all column names (m.my_column_reference). It becomes essential in more complex queries, and is anyway good practice, because it makes things much clearer when you come to revisit old queries